# Show the arrow of dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a dropdown list in my spreadsheet. I did it using data validation but I want to make an arrow in the cell for that list.

All the answers suggest the solution in the photo which I can't find it in my spreadsheet at all.

[image: suggested solutions]

Answer (score 0):

- **right click on a cell, row, column or range**
- click on the last option - **Data validation**
- window opens which will look like your picture

[image]

Comment: @AhmadSayedAbdulrahman it "exists" only if **Criteria** is set on `List from range` or `List of items`